# Loop through code for multiple data sets - stop when blank cell found

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Ok, maybe I need to revise this to get more of a response  **; )**

The code below works fine and does the following;

It looks up the required data shown in columns B (with column C being the copy destination via an offset number)

[image: Item Locations]

which directs it to the following data - picking up all the information in cells B12:B23;

[image: Source Data]

It then pastes this information in the following sheet;

[image: Data Destination]

All fine so far. Now what I need it to do is look up the remaining information in columns D, F, H, J & L of the source data, and paste it on the subsequent rows underneath the data shown above.

```
Private Sub MultipleItemExtract(strFileName As String, rngItem As Range, rngDataWrite As Range)

' Copies all data in specified cell addresses of specified worksheets
' of strFileName to specified columns of row rngDataWrite in active sheet.
'

' parameters:   strFileName - data type String - name of file to search in
'               rngDataWrite - data type Range - write location
'               rngWSandItems - data type Range - worksheet and items location
'               rngColumn - data type Range - destination column location
'
' notes for external parameters (in "Parameters" worksheet):
'   Data from separate worksheets to be exactly one line apart
'   Data from within the same worksheet to be zero lines apart
'   Do not insert columns between the "Item", "Address" and "Destination" columns

Dim strCurrentWorksheet As String

While rngItem <> ""

    'set current worksheet
    strCurrentWorksheet = rngItem
    'move to items
    Set rngItem = rngItem.Offset(1, 0)

    With Workbooks(strFileName).Worksheets(strCurrentWorksheet)
        While rngItem <> ""
            Cells(rngDataWrite.row, rngItem.Offset(0, 2)) = .Range(rngItem.Offset(0, 1).Value)
            Set rngItem = rngItem.Offset(1, 0)
        Wend
    End With

    'skip the space between worksheets
    Set rngItem = rngItem.Offset(1, 0)
Wend

End Sub
```

I'm more than willing to get on the chat facility on here to discuss if need be, I really need to work this out and I appreciate all your input.

Thank you all!
Matt

Comment: A shiny e-penny for whoever helps me out?  : D

Comment: Really? Noone is willing to help?  :(

Comment: Ok, what can i do to get an answer to this? Do i need to increase my bounty or something??

Comment: Sad face. What can I do to get help?? This is the best site for this sort of question and no one wants to help! :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to explain better how the sheets are formatted. If there is any space between the information for example.

Now to your code.
Isn't this line throwing an error?

```
strCurrentWorksheet = rngItem
```

**strCurrentWorksheet** is a String while **rngItem** is a Range.

If your information has any white spaces I would recommend getting the row from the function that calls the last cell used.

```
set lastCell = Sheets().Cells.SpecialCells xlCellTypeLastCell
```

And afterwards do

```
lastRow = Cells(lastCell.Row, columnNeeded).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

to get the row, or the range if it's what you need.

Afterwards you can change it's value to what you need.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you, I'll investigate a bit later on how best I can restructure the question, and I'll give your suggestions a try.